# Why does including a custom struct actually increase the size of my c# class?

Tags: c#, memory, struct

I have a class with several floats, along with a few other fields...

```
 public class tResult
    {
    public byte Days;
    public int UpCount;
    public int DownCount;
    public int SameCount;
    public float UpRatio;
    public float DownRatio;
    public float SameRatio;
    public float UpAverage;
    public float DownAverage;
    public float Average;
    public float OccurancesCF;
    public float DirectionCF;
    }
```

using `Float` instead of `Percentage`, my class takes 88 bytes each (using Jon Skeet's test creating 1M instances between `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)` calls).

When I replace 5 of the `floats` (4 bytes) with a `percentage` class (2 bytes of data) my size increases to 96 bytes.

```
public struct Percentage : IComparable
{
    public Int16 Hundredths;
    public Percentage(double X) { Hundredths = (Int16)(X * 100); }
    public double Ratio { get { return Hundredths / 100.0; } set { Hundredths = (Int16)(value * 100); } }
    public override string ToString() => (Hundredths / 100.0).ToString("##0.00");
    public int CompareTo(object obj) => Hundredths.CompareTo(((Percentage)obj).Hundredths);
}
```

and

```
    public class tResult
    {
            public byte Days;
            public int UpCount;
            public int DownCount;
            public int SameCount;
            public Percentage UpRatio;
            public Percentage DownRatio;
            public Percentage SameRatio;
            public float UpAverage;
            public float DownAverage;
            public float Average;
            public Percentage OccurancesCF;
            public Percentage DirectionCF;
    }
```

My question is why did it go up instead of down?  Everything I've read here on SO (including posts by Jon and Eric Lippert) makes me think they should be laid out reordered by size, and therefore should have decreased by ~10 bytes.

Comment: I'm going to assume that alignment of the `Percentage` members within the class is causing this behavior. The compiler probably won't align them on 2 byte boundaries. Try adding another two bytes to Percentage  and see if it makes no difference.

Comment: Add result class with 'Percentage', please.

Comment: Jonathan, I added another 2 byte variable and it made no difference.

Comment: Your measurements do not appear to be accurate, in 32-bit mode it goes from 56 to 56 bytes, in 64-bit mode it goes from 64 to 88 bytes.  A float is always aligned to 4, a struct is aligned to 4 in 32-bit mode, aligned to 8 in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @hans - This is in debug mode on 64-bit.Internal values types (int16, byte, etc) don't seem to align to 8 bytes, is there a way to duplicate this in our own constructs?  I could use int16, with extension methods to make a 2 byte FP number (perfect for percentages) but was obviously wanting to do it with a struct.

Comment: If you like Int16 then you are not using enough of them.  You can add as many properties as you want, they don't affect object/struct size.